# How to append current page contents to another page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two HTML pages, one is source page and the other one is copy, I need to pass some div elements into other(copy) page body. I did half way, here I used setTimeOut function to achieve it
How it can done without the timeout function?
and browser should display the url.

source page:

```
<html>
    <head>        
        <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <script>
            function copyCon(){
                
            var p = document.getElementById("1");
            var p_prime = p.cloneNode(true);
            var w    = window.open('printcopy.html');
            
            setTimeout(function(){ 
                w.document.body.appendChild(p_prime);
            }, 1000);
            }
            
        </script>
        
        <button onclick="copyCon()">copy </button>
        <div id = "1" style="width: 500px; height: 500px; border: 1px solid black; position: relative">
            
            <h3> this is a test heading </h3>
            <p style="top: 60px; left: 20px; position: absolute;"> test Paragraph</p>
            
            <input type="text" style="position: absolute; top: 40px; left: 20px"/>
            
        </div>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

copy:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>        
    </body> </html>
```

and is there any way to access the elements and execute function of copy page?

Comment: What is the reason of using ``setTimeOut`` and what URL should be displayed by browser?

Comment: take a look  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155122/copy-current-webpage-into-a-new-window     or   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22245608/javascript-how-to-copy-div-content-to-another-page

Comment: I'm with @Kamil what the reason of the timeout? I think that your code without timeout should do the job. What happend when you try without the timeout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution myself

```
function copyCon(){


   var w    = window.open('printcopy.html');
   w.onload = function(){
     var p = document.getElementById("1");
     var p_prime = p.cloneNode(true);
     w.document.body.appendChild(p_prime);
   };
 }
```

thanks for supporting

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by using the $.get function ([documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)).

In the file you want to append elements from copying (assuming you have a div called `div_you_want_to_be_append`):

```
$.get('source.php', function (data) {
    $('#div_you_want_to_be_append').append(data);
});
```

The best way to avoid new HTML tags, is to include the content you want to copy to a new file in PHP and call include it in the source and call in $.get function (file : `source.php` in my example)