# copy content from one page to another JS

Tags: javascript

Suppose i know the id of a div from other page - can plain java script can copy the content from one page to other page?
This is my function with empty place for your answer (if that possible):

```
function copyPaste() {
  var dataPage2 = 'path-to-data-div-from-page2'.innerHTML;

  document.write ("<section id='example'></section>");
  document.getElementById("example").innerHTML = dataPage2;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by another page?

Comment: I thin you can look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203530/accessing-the-content-of-other-tabs-in-browser

Comment: javascript is running on the html DOM and its parent/root scope it the document. So it can only be act on one document at a time. You can load the **path-to-data-div-from-page2** page and store it's content in localStorage and can be accessed in another page while loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Page 1:

```
var pageContent = document.getElementById("myDiv1").innerHTML; 
sessionStorage.setItem("page1content", pageContent);
```

Page 2:

```
document.getElementById("myDiv2").innerHTML=sessionStorage.getItem("page1content");
```

Credits:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22245779/5192105

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there any way calling the function without modifying both pages?

Comment: This is a way of accessing the item without modifying ur pages.

Answer (score 0):

```
function copyPaste() {

document.write ("<div id='test' style='display:none' ></div>");

$( "#test" ).load( "http:url_of_web_Page #id" );

 var dataPage2 = $('#test').innerHTML;

 document.write ("<section id='example'></section>");
 document.getElementById("example").innerHTML = dataPage2;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this not working. It returns "undefined"